# Swift UISlider that gets its values from an array of numbers

Tags: arrays, swift, uislider

I'm a newbie to swift and believe me I've searched and searched for an answer already. I want to create UISliders that get their values from an array of numbers in Swift. Its a camera app so the example array should be obvious.

```
@IBAction func isoValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    let isoArray = ["24", "32", "50","64","80","100","125","160","200","250","320","400","500","640","720","800","1000","1250","1600","1800"] // available iPhone 6s ISO settings I believe
    let currentValue = // What do I need?
    isoText.text = "\(currentValue)"
}
```

Even harder would be representing shutter speeds from 1/1000 - 32!
From what I see out there this is not an easy one because there is no mathematical representation to calc from the array. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you want this for but I'm guessing this is right.

```
// Global Variable or something like this (accessible from multiple functions)
let isoArray = ["24", "32", "50","64","80","100","125","160","200","250","320","400","500","640","720","800","1000","1250","1600","1800"] // available iPhone 6s ISO settings I believe

func functionThatCreatesTheSliderYo(...) {
    slider.minimumValue = 0
    slider.maximumValue = isoArray.count
    slider.continuous = false
}

@IBAction func isoValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    // instead of Int(val) you may want to round(val) for a better UI
    let currentValue = isoArray[Int(sender.value)]
    isoText.text = "\(currentValue)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand why the array becomes global but I don't quite understand "func functionThatCreatesTheSliderYo(...)" @IBOutlet weak var isoSlider: UISlider! Sorry, in the learning phase.

Comment: right. the difference is that outlets are created via a storyboard and UISliders are created programatically.

Outlets are UISlider objects just fancily changed for the XCode Storyboard interface. You should be able to set the `outlet.minimumValue = 0` (or `(outlet as! UISlider).minimumValue = 0`. If all that doesnt work, you should be able to set the `.minimumValue` on the storyboard `attributes` section.

Comment: func isoSlider(sender: UISlider) {
        isoSlider.minimumValue = 0
        isoSlider.maximumValue = isoArray.count
        isoSlider.continuous = false
    }  Doesn't work, but that was my first thought. Ohh and round threw error

Comment: Set the minvalue in the Attributes Inspector in the Storyboard to 0 and the maxvalue to 20. Then the `isoValueChanged` function should work

Comment: Attributes in the storyboard were already minvalue 0, maxvalue 1600 isoSlider.maximumValue = isoArray.count = error: Cannot assign value of type int to a value of type float. I'll keep trying.

Comment: If you set the min and max value in the storyboard, ignore the `functionThatCreatesTheSliderYo` function. Just use the `isoValueChanged` function

Comment: Kind of works. I will post the results as soon as I can go through the new issues.

Comment: That works as [Int()] but trying this on the other array fails because the values are from 1/1000 to 32, not Int. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
    @IBAction func isoValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    let isoArray = ["24", "32", "50","64","80","100","125","160","200","250","320","400","500","640","720","800","1000","1250","1600","1800"]
    let currentValue = isoArray[Int(sender.value)]
    isoText.text = "\(currentValue)"

}
```

So simple as it should be in Swift. Many thanks to Ty. Be sure to see the chat though.